# Overwrite a type to make it more concise when optional

Tags: typescript

Given this example:

```js
type A = (arg?: string) => void

const myObject : { a: A } = {
    a: (arg: "yes" | "no") => { console.log(1)}

 }
```

I get an error:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"yes" | "no"'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '"yes" | "no"'
```

Even if I make `arg?: "yes" | "no"` it then returns a:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"yes" | "no" | undefined
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"yes" | "no" | undefined'
```

I wonder if there is any way that I can make `arg` more precisely typed ("yes" | "no" instead of string) when is an optional argument. Assume that I cannot touch `type A`

Comment: Why is `myObject` typed as `{ a: A }` if you don't want the `a` property to be of type `A`?

Comment: It comes from a external library which requires a to be interface A which has that optional value, but I want to force it as non null

Comment: Why? If it is marked as optional then expect it to be. Don't force it to be non-nullable unless you are 100% certain that it cannot possibly be null or undefined.

Comment: How could I then define that, if it is defined, be "yes" | "no", but if is undefined, is okey

Comment: If you cannot touch `A`, then you either have to deal with it, or make your own type that allows it to ... essentially not be `A`

Comment: Is there not a type that can be considered like a equal type to A but with a more specific type of string ? @mike

Comment: You're asking for something that's not type safe.  The errors are there for a reason. You can always *assert* that `myObject` is of type `{a: A}` but then you're setting yourself up for potential problems at runtime if the implementation actually cares about the value being `"yes" | "no" | undefined`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXKdVW).  Do you really want to do that?

Comment: I mean, my car has a warning noise that sounds if the driver isn't wearing a seat belt.  The correct way to fix that is to wear the seat belt.  You're asking how to drive without a seat belt and without the warning noise.  That's definitely possible (e.g., buckle the seat belt before you get into the car and sit on the seat belt), but it's not really the sort of advice others should be comfortable giving you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract (interface) is determined by the type A.

You can't assign something that is narrower (or different), because when you call `myObject.a` you would be using the contract defined by `A`.  So what you assign MUST accept the shape defined by `A`.

```
myObject.a('foo')  // valid, as 'foo' is a string, as per A's interface
```

To allow assignment of something other than `A` to `myObject.a` would mean that the supplied function could receive something unintended, which would defeat the purpose of type safety.

If you can't change the definition of `A`, then you will have to implement the function assigned to `myObject.a` with the same interface as `A`, and make a runtime check to see if the supplied arg conforms to "yes" | "no".  A simple comparison will suffice, or if it becomes more complex, you can consider a type guard, which will narrow the scope for the remainder of the block.

Comment: Thanks I understood this a bit later and I like to think that is okey to say that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine:

```js
const a1: 'yes' | 'no' = 'yes'
const a2: string | undefined = a1
```

This is not:

```js
const b1: string | undefined = 'yes'
const b2: 'yes' | 'no' = b1 // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"yes" | "no"'
```

In functions as well:

```js
type A = (arg?: string) => void
const f: A = (arg: 'yes' | 'no') => { console.log(arg.toUpperCase()) }
// Error: Type '(arg: 'yes' | 'no') => void' is not assignable to type 'A'
```

If we ignore the TypeScript error there is a risk to get a runtime error:

```js
const f: A = ((arg: 'yes' | 'no') => { console.log(arg.toUpperCase()) }) as A
f(undefined) // Runtime Error!
```

`arg?: "yes" | "no"` is not the answer because there is still a risk:

```js
const f: A = ((arg?: 'yes' | 'no') => {
  if (arg) {
    console.log(arg[1].toUpperCase()) // log second char as upper case
  }
}) as A
f('A') // Runtime Error!
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I accepted other one that brings more clarity on why i should not be able to do it

Answer (score 1):

You have a choice to make. Option 1:

```
type A = (arg?: 'yes'|'no') => void
const myObject : { a: A } = {
    a: (arg?: 'yes'|'no') => { console.log(1)}
}
```

Option 2:

```
type A = (arg?: string) => void
const myObject : { a: A } = {
    a: (arg?: string) => { console.log(1)}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you did not consider that i cannot touch type A. If it is not possible is good to state it